# Prisma: Is there any way to execute javascript as default value of prisma data type?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

in my data model, as the type of id, I want to generate a default value that will start with the user.

so the id will bed something like this `user..rear33422qeqr`

```
type User {

  myId: String! @default (`user${2+2}`)
  name: String!
  email: String! @unique

}
```

is it possible to call a javascript function or using string interpolation (`user${2+2}`)

Comment: Frankly, I didn't understand what you want to do, do you want to generate a random string and append it to your user?

Comment: I want to customize the auto generated prisma id. by default all id starts with ck...
for example this is a valid prisma id , which is auto generated. `ck9rni8rv001507190wwmatgy`

but I want to customize this. so that all user's id will be `user--randomDigit/randomString` and all post's id will be `posts--randomDigit/randomString`

Comment: There is an open issue on Prisma's GitHub to support custom ID patterns. Somebody proposed a [solution](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6719#issuecomment-1178211695) based on the possibility to register [middlewares](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/middleware). It may not be perfect but it's working.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since prisma only uses sql queries. So you would need to write an sql function (`CREATE SEQUENCE`) for this, and push it to the database via a migration.